# Prove the lower bound

Tags: analysis

Knowing That $ A \land B \subset \mathbb{R}$ and they both have a lower bound. Prove that (most likely using the definition of a bound):
$$\inf (A \div B)=\min\{ \inf A,\ \inf B \}, $$ where $A \div B$ is the symmetric difference
$$ A \div B := (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false without further specifications. 
$$A=\{1,\ 2,\ 3\}\implies \inf(A) = 1$$
$$B=\{1,\ 3,\ 5\}\implies \inf(B) = 1$$
Taking these two gives
$$A\div B = \{2,\ 5\}\implies \inf(A\div B) = 2\neq \min\{1,\ 1\}$$

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe if I wasn't trying to prove something that is not true but rather think about it in general I would do it myself. Thanks!